# Modify jar file (.class file)

Tags: java, eclipse, class, jar, build

I just want to update .class files (ConfigUtils.class) into jar file (utils-X-X.jar) under Referenced Librairies into Eclipse.

My Eclipse project treeview :

> - [Project Name X]
>
>   - src/main/java
>   - src/test/conf
>       ...
>   - References Librairies
>
>     - utils-X-X.jar
>
>       - xx.xx.xxx.xxx.1
>
>         - [...]
>         - ConfigUtils.class

I am able to decompile class file and view source code.

Now, I want to update the class file and reintegrate it into utils-X-X.jar and then buildthe whole project.
How can I proceed ?

Thanks in advance for your support.

Best regards

Comment: Why don't you submit a bug/feature request to the owner of this library, and get a fixed library jar instead. If it's your own library, why don't you rebuild it from sources instead of decompiling and recompiling. That looks like duct-tape engineering to me. That said, a jar file is a zip file. You extract the jar, replace a file, re-create the jar file, and you're done.

Comment: If you got the source code you can compile the code normally, give that you have all the dependent class in the class path.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just I would like to test first without the source code.. if it seems not possible, I will contact the owner of the librairy.